# getting search through Advance Custom Field post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a problem in searching my post in wordpress. I cannot search my post because of i am using advance custom fields and i created another text area. how can i get the post from advance custom fields by using default wordpress search bar. Here is my search. I put my text post in my custom field in text area.

here is my search code :

```
<?php 
                    if( have_posts() ) :
                        while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                            <?php get_template_part('content', 'search'); ?>

                        <?php endwhile;
                    endif;
?>
```

Here is my content-search.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php the_title('<h1 class="entry-title">','</h1>'); ?>

    <small><?php the_category(' '); ?> || <?php the_tags(); ?> || <?php edit_post_link(); ?> </small>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <hr>
</article>
```

Comment: any answers pls